# CSS issue with Asp.net Menu control in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: asp.net, css, aspmenu-control

I worked previously with ASP.Net Menu control & it worked fine, In my latest project i am using the same menu control but for some reason menu keeps on adding additional space on left side of menu when clicked. Please look at two screenshots.

I have this issue only with IE 8 & below version not with any other browser

[Live Example of website](http://tinyurl.com/c99epn5)

Internet Explorer 8 on actual Machine
[image: Internet Explorer 8 on actual Machine]

Internet Explorer 8 using IE Tester
[image: Internet Explorer 8 using IE Tester]

I have been struggling with this design issue for last few days as i am not able to figure out what property is causing... This is noticeable only if you have actual Internet Explorer 8 installed on you system or if you using IE tester and test it for IE 8 version.

If you have higher version as i have IE 9 i check it using F12 but it doesn't show any design issue in IE 8 either in standard or compatible mode.

I would appreciate help in this regarding as i am not an expert on  CSS.

Answer (score 0):

At last resolved the issue. problem was due CSS property conflict, i had wrote CSS in following manner which was creating problem. I wrote both classes separately to resolve the issue

```
.LNMore a:link, a:visited 
{
    float:left;
    width:160px;
    height:15px;
    font-family:Tahoma;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:right;
    font-size:12px;
    padding-left:0px;
    padding-top:6px;
    color:White;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```